# In rails, I need to make a a lib file, and access models from it. How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need very basic and detailed explanations, a ELI5 (explain like I'm 5) style explanation.

I've never had a problem learning c++, c#, objective-c, visual basic, qbasic, powerbuilder, this list goes on and on and on.

But ruby and rails just goes right over my head. Perhaps it's working in a non-IDE.

Anyway, I'm trying to create a webscraper using nokogiri, with the eventual goal to run this scraping file on the server side in a scheduled job.

I have created a file /lib/api/v1/scraper.rb for this.

My file is just one big wall of text currently.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "www.example.com"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
...do stuff
```

I need to be able to call some of my models from this file, but am unable to as I receive this error

```
uninitialized constant ModelName (NameError)
```

1) How can I call my models from this file? ELI5.

2) I need to scrape multiple different types of information, from a few different pages. Should I create multiple .rb files for this, and have one 'scraper' file with various different definitions/functions? ELI5.

3) Should my scraper.rb be a class or module? What's the difference? I'm guessing you can instantiate a class, but a module is just a list of static definitions? In this case, how can I create a module with various definitions such as `scrape_price_data` and `scrape_expiration_dates`... yet have them all called. I want them all to be run. Is there some sort of main() function in which I can then call each of the definitions I've made one after the other. Or if I run the file via `ruby lib/api/v1/scraper.rb', is it going to run each definition once top down? ELI5.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not 5. Don't act like that.

Comment: As for (1), I suppose you're not using rails, so, have you tried requiring it with ```require './model/model_name.rb'```?

Comment: @sevenseacat it's a reference to a very popular a default subreddit called /r/eli5

Comment: @ThyagoB.Rodrigues I just tried that but no luck. I then end up getting an error on the first line of the model file I'm trying to require. `...../app/models/modelname.rb:1:in '<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)`

Answer (score 1):

Make your scraper.rb a module with `module Scraper`. In order to use it in your other files, put `include 'Scraper'`. Now you can use the methods that were in scraper.rb as if it was in the file that you are currently in.

Now in your config/application.rb, put this in the class so that rails know where to include 'Scraper' from

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/api/v1)
```

Comment: how can I access models from the scraper module? If I try to access a model such as `MyModel.all`, I get this error `lib/api/v1/scraper.rb:17:in '<module:Scraper>': uninitialized constant MyModel (NameError)`

Comment: do you have a my_models table in the database?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to access Position.all. I have a /app/models.position.rb, and positions table. But I get that error. Any idea?

Comment: you will need to use self.class.all in that case. self is a Position object, self.class will return Position, then you will have Position.all

Comment: In lib/api1/v1/scraper.rb I use `self.position.all` to obtain the equivalent of `Postition.all`?

Comment: how are you calling this module?

Comment: all I'm doing right now is running it from the terminal while I test the scraper. "ruby /lib/api/v1/scraper.rb". I want to access a few different models from this scraper file, position, and a couple others.

Comment: how can I call my various models like `Position` and others, and access the data in them?